# Trivial Math Problem - Magnitudes and Simplification

Tags: complex-numbers

Good day, everybody!

I was handed this problem by a friend. 
Prove that  $|z|=1$ if $z^n=1$.

$z$, in this case, is a complex number.

It should be very easy, but I'm missing something....

Could someone please provide a step by step solution?
So far, I've tried taking the magnitude of both sides of the given equation, but I don't know what to do after...

Comment: Can you prove that in general $|z^n|=|z|^n$?

Comment: Have you seen the polar form of complex numbers?  If so, here's a hint: try re-writing everything using polar form.

Comment: Can you show that $|wz| = |w||z|$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes, I can! But how does that help? Can I just take the nth root of 1 and call it a day? Complex numbers can multiply to 1 to, as well, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the hint of the first comment you have $$1=z^n\implies 1=|z^n|=|z|^n$$

Since $|z|$ is a non-negative real number, it must be $1$, because $1$ is the only solution of $x^n=1$ in non-negative real numbers. To see that consider the cases $0\le x<1$ and $x>1$.

Comment: Brilliant! I (somehow conveniently) forgot about the fact that the magnitude must be a positive, real number. Thanks @PeterSmith!